# CABasicAnimation originates from top right rather than center

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uikit, cabasicanimation

I have a circle that I animate growing outwards and getting bigger.  Unfortunately despite me setting the `anchorPoint` it doesnt animate from the center outwards, it seems to lock position top left.  What is going on?

See this image that depicts the circles off center

[image]

Code

```
- (void)setLayerProperties {
    rippleLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    rippleLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;

    rippleLayer.strokeColor = _Color.CGColor;
    //rippleLayer.contentsGravity = @"center";
    rippleLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,0.5);
    rippleLayer.bounds = self.bounds;

    rippleLayer.path = bezierPath.CGPath;
    [self.layer addSublayer:rippleLayer];
}

// Now animate the circle outwards
rippleLayer.opacity = 1;
CABasicAnimation *scale = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
[scale setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f]];
[scale setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0f]];
[scale setRepeatCount:1];
[scale setDuration:1.0f];
//[scale setRemovedOnCompletion:YES];
[scale setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];

[rippleLayer addAnimation:scale forKey:scale.keyPath];
```

Comment: check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495956/calayer-cabasicanimation-not-scaling-around-center-anchorpoint?rq=1

Comment: @lionserdar Thanks, I already have and do set my bounds - is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

To scale layer at it's center, you need to set layer's position.This may help you

[I want to draw a Smooth animations in iOS using CAPropertyAnimations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19513117/i-want-to-draw-a-smooth-animations-in-ios-using-capropertyanimations)

## define RADIANS(angle) ((angle) / 180.0 * M_PI)

```
CGPoint testCenter = CGPointMake(144.5, 230.0);
CAShapeLayer *aTestLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
aTestLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:**CGPointZero** radius:15.0 startAngle:RADIANS(0) endAngle:RADIANS(360) clockwise:YES].CGPath;
aTestLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
aTestLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
**aTestLayer.position = testCenter;**
aTestLayer.borderWidth = 2.0;

[self.view.layer addSublayer:aTestLayer];

CABasicAnimation *pulse = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
pulse.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
pulse.duration = 2;
pulse.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
pulse.autoreverses = YES;
pulse.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
pulse.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0];


[aTestLayer addAnimation:pulse forKey:nil];
```